# Where to start with the Apostolic Fathers

Tags: greek

I'm looking to start reading the Apostolic Fathers (in Koine), using Michael Holmes' [The Apostolic Fathers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/770124.The_Apostolic_Fathers). Which of the fathers' Greek is most accessible, or most similar to that of the New Testament?

Comment: Michael Holmes' volume is in valuable - a great choice for such an exercise - great choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Clement may be a useful place to start in that it's written by a pupil of the apostles, it's early, and it's written in the form of a New Testament epistle.

It's a first century document (admittedly the Koine Greek isn't going to change much between late first and early second centuries though), but that puts it very close in time and language to the New Testament authors. Edmundson even argued it was written in AD 70 - his background on the Apostolic Fathers in general and on 1 Clement specifically is very valuable. See [here](https://ccel.org/ccel/edmundson/church/church.iii.html), especially lecture 7 for 1 Clement.